# compile a static kernel driver to module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I am compiling linux kernel version 3.17. by default a driver is statically compiled into the linux kernel and is probed at boot time. But I want this particular driver to be build as a module so I changed the **CONFIG_driver** from 'y' to 'm'. But after doing so the kernel outputs an undefined reference error and breaks the build.

following console log

```
|   LD      drivers/built-in.o
|   LINK    vmlinux
|   LD      vmlinux.o
|   MODPOST vmlinux.o
|   GEN     .version
|   CHK     include/generated/compile.h
|   UPD     include/generated/compile.h
|   CC      init/version.o
|   LD      init/built-in.o
| drivers/built-in.o: In function `adv7511_irq_handler':
| /var/adnan/work/git/mel_repos/mel_cedar_2/build/build_zedboard-zynq7-mel/tmp/work-shared/zedboard-zynq7-mel/kernel-source/drivers/gpu/drm/i2c/adv7511_core.c:314: undefined reference to `drm_helper_hpd_irq_event'
| make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

where as the function `drm_helper_hpd_irq_event` is present in **drm_probe_helper.c**. and according to the makefile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER) += drm_kms_helper.o
```

the module which I am building selects **CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER**. In the .config this is directly proportional to my module when I build my module this also gets build in module and otherwise it build statically. But when it builds in module the file is not compiled.

Any Idea ? How can I force this into static build while doing my driver in module ?

Comment: Please, put here exact output of comiler.

Comment: Does said driver actually support being built as a module (as in, is its Kconfig entry "tristate", or just "bool")?

Comment: Provide the lines around the error one. It seems the module requires symbols which are not exported to the modules.

Comment: Check out [this link on `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch16lev1sec7).

Comment: Is DRM_KMS_HELPER set to be built ?

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, you can replace

```
obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER) += drm_kms_helper.o
```

by

```
obj-y += drm_kms_helper.o
```

Comment: Why not just `CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER=y`?

Comment: @Andy Shevchenko: this would'nt work as you can't directly select the state of CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER, Kbuild would always overwrite its value each time the kernel is build. That option is always selected by an other one and will take the value 'm' if one of the selectors in the chain is 'm'.

Comment: @theadnangondal: can you point to the kernel sources you are trying to build and the defconfig you are using or the .config you have?

Comment: `make CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER=y` should work I suppose.